# jQuery functions not being called in IE when page is being loaded via AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'm loading page content that contains jquery code via Ajax. There are no problems in Firefox and Chrome. In IE, none of the jquery code in the loaded page gets called. How do I work around this?

This is the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Bow &amp; Wow Petparazzi on Video</title>
<!-- Include support libraries first -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px">

<div id="ajax_div">
   <div id="click">click</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$("#click").live('click', function () {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "targ.php",
      data: "a=a",
      success: function(msg){
         $("#ajax_div").html(msg);
      }
   });
});
-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page that gets loaded:

```
<div id="bah">bah</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$("#bah").live('click', function() {
   alert("bah");
});
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE will not process `<script>` tag inside inserted HTML. Various AJAX libraries will workaround that by stripping script tags and processing them manually.

Use the `$("#ajax_div").load("targ.php", ...);` and it should work.

Comment: replaced the ajax call to

       $("#click").load("targ.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
      $("#ajax_div").html(response);
   });

but it still didn't work.